# unable to delete items from cart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, use-state, react-context

I want to delete items from shopping cart with context API.
I want to delete items one by one. For example there are five count from a product, I want to say if there's more than one product minus one by one, else (there is only one) delete whole product

Items data come from JSON file

First I used this code

```
import { createContext, useState } from "react";
const CartContext = createContext();

export function CartProvider({ children }) {
    const [items , setItems] = useState([]);

    const AddToCart = (photo,price,title,des,id,count)=>{

        const product = items.find(item=> item.id === id);

        if (product) {
            product.count+=1  ;
            const products = items.find(item=> item.id !== id);
            items.count =1; 
            return[...products, product]
        }
        setItems((prevState) => [...prevState, {photo,price,title,des,id,count}]);
    }
    const DeleteItemCart = (id) => {
        const product = items.find(item=> item.id === id);
            if(product.count>1){
                product.count -=1;
            }
         else{
        const deleted = items.filter((product) => parseInt(product.id) !== parseInt(id));
        setItems(deleted);}
       };

  return <CartContext.Provider value={{items,AddToCart,DeleteItemCart}}>
    {children}
    </CartContext.Provider>;
}

export default CartContext;
```

In console.log everything is right and number of items reduced one by one. But it did not work in page and items number was fixed.

I supposed it's better to put count in a state so I write this code

```
const product = items.find(item=> item.id === id);
const[counter, setCounter] = useState(product.count)
const DeleteItemCart = (id) => {
            if(counter>1){
                const prev =product.count
                setCounter(prev => prev-1)
                console.log(counter)
            }
            
         else{
        const deleted = items.filter((product) => product.id !== id);
        setItems(deleted);}
       };
```

but still have error

Comment: share the entire code of your component or hook where this is being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to convert your data into integer for your ID.

eg:- Try this method

```
const DeleteItemCart = (id) => {
    const newTemp = [...items];
    const product = newTemp.find(item=> parseInt(item.id) === parseInt(id));
        if(product.count>1){
            product.count -=1;
            setItems(newTemp);// you missed this after reducing to 1
        }

     else{
    const deleted = items.filter((product) => parseInt(product.id) !== parseInt(id));
    setItems(deleted);}
   };
```

Comment: there is a problem. for example there are five count from a product, i want to say if there's more than one product minus one by one, else(there is only one) delete whole product

Comment: Ok try this `parseInt(product.id) !== parseInt(id)` where you have been using

Comment: it's same as before

Comment: try edit answer

Comment: sadly same as before

Comment: check answer with edited comment line.

Comment: thank you, setItems(newTemp) was true. problem solved

Comment: no problem, enjoy coding